# Magento 2.2.1: Admin Access Denied

Tags: admin, magento-2.2.1

I stumbled with this problem earlier. I've attached a screenshot below for your reference. If you have any ideas just let me know.

[image]

If I will run php bin/magento setup:upgrade it will show an error

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Are you admin user of this Portal ?

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. Have you managed to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the user you are using has no permission. Try logging in with Admin role user.
If that also not remember you can get it from DB.

1. Go to your database and search for `admin_user` table
2. In admin_user table find the admin user.
3. Reset the password field by selecting the function as MD5 form the drop-down in the function column.Now in the value field, type the password and hit Go.

Now try using admin credentials to login.

Comment: Hello I tried your approach but it's not working in my end. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Are you using admin role credentials?

Answer (score 0):

***Create new admin user using following code***

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user='newadmin' --admin-password='admin#123' --admin-email='admin@domain.com' --admin-firstname='admintest' --admin-lastname='admintestLast'
```

Run this into **M2** **Root** directory.

Comment: Hello I already tried this one yesterday but still the same issue. Thanks for the answer